# Are there any health concerns to regular consumption of liquified bone and marrow smoothie?

Tags: nutrition, digestion, bones, bone-marrow

I blend up the cooked bone in my steaks into a savory smoothie. I like to think it's a superfood meal. I am, however, not a licensed/doctoral nutritionist, so I'm not sure about the health benefits or detriments.

Comment: Hi @yarlo and welcome to health.SE! Could you please provide some more information about what else you put into the smoothie? I reworded the question so that it would attract less opinion-based answers.

Comment: I feel as if this may sit better in Biology.SE. We would be able to inform you what is actually in the Bone marrow and dispose of the many myths regarded it's gastrointestinal consumption - and not sound out of bounds of Health.SE. Stuff as such, I feel are off-topic in Health.SE. Even yet, Skeptics.SE, may have much to add?